# C# Speech Recognizing Multiple Words together? (Recognize a sentence)

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, speech, sentence

I'm building an application that recognizes multiple words from a user; thus putting together a sentence using the words recognized.

Here's what I have as of now:

```
namespace SentenceRecognitionFramework__v1_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        SpeechRecognitionEngine recog = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
        SpeechSynthesizer sp = new SpeechSynthesizer();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnListen_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Choices sList = new Choices();
            sList.Add(new String[] { "what","is", "a", "car" });

            Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(sList));

            recog.RequestRecognizerUpdate();
            recog.LoadGrammar(gr);
            recog.SpeechRecognized += sRecognize_SpeechRecognized;
            recog.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();
            recog.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);
            recog.SpeechRecognitionRejected += sRecognize_SpeechRecognitionRejected;
        }

        private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
        {
            sentenceBox.Text = "Sorry, I couldn't recognize";
        }

        private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            sentenceBox.Text = e.Result.Text.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

**HOWEVER, this code will only recognize one word at a time. Even if I edit my code to do this:**

```
private void sRecognize_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
        {
            sentenceBox.Text = sentenceBox.Text + " " + e.Result.Text.ToString();
        }
```

The application cannot **continuously** recognize words when I utter the words "What is a car" *continuously without having breaks when I speak them out.*

What changes can I make in order for the program to recognize an entire sentence built using those words defined, without having to have *speech breaks* when uttering the sentence?

Output required:

> > I utter the sentence: *What is a car*
> >
> > Application displays: **What is a car**

PERFECT Example: **Google Speech Recognition** Google develops a sentence using the words available in their word library

Thank you kindly :)

Answer (score 4):

It recognizes one word because you incorrectly constructed the grammar. Since you constructed the grammar consisting of choice of **one of the words** "what", "is", "a", "car" it exactly recognizes one of the words.

You probably want to read introduction into grammars and related documentation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh378438(v=office.14).aspx

If you want to construct the grammar describing the phrase you can just use GrammarBuilder like this:

```
  Grammar gr = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder("what is a car"));
```

This grammar will recognize a phrase.

To understand how Choices work you can read documentation on Choices:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.speech.recognition.choices(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 3):

This answer may be a little late, but I have not found any other place with an actual answer to this problem. So to save others the the time and frustration, here is how I did it.

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Synthesis;
using System.Speech.Recognition;

namespace SpeachTest
{
public class GrammerTest
{
        static void Main()
        {
        Choices choiceList = new Choices();
        choiceList.Add(new string[]{"what", "is", "a", "car", "are", "you", "robot"} );

        GrammarBuilder builder = new GrammarBuilder();
        builder.Append(choiceList);
        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(new GrammarBuilder(builder, 0, 4) );   //Will recognize a minimum of 0 choices, and a maximum of 4 choices

            SpeechRecognizer speechReco = new SpeechRecognizer();
            speechReco.LoadGrammar(grammar);



        }
}
}
```

The key here is this line

> new GrammarBuilder(builder, 0, 4)

This tells the speech recognizer to recognize, up to 4 repetitions of elements form `builder`, and a minimum of zero.

So it will now recognize

```
"what is a car"
```

And if you want more than 4 repetitions, just change `new GrammarBuilder(builder, 0, 4)`

to

```
new GrammarBuilder(builder, 0 "the number of repetitions you want")
```

See this for more info  [GrammarBuilder(builder, minRepeat, maxRepeat)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms554231%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `richTextBox` instead of `textbox` and then append `e.result.text`, like:

```
richtextbox.append(e.result.text)
```