# C# Speech: Recognize multiple words?

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, grammar, speech

How do I recognize, suppose: 2 words from a set of given Choices? Couldn't find an answer to this on SO.

This is my recognition code:

```
GrammarBuilder questionType = new Choices(new string[] { "The" });

GrammarBuilder connector = new Choices(new string[] { "cat", "dog" });

GrammarBuilder connector2 = new Choices(new string[] { "jumped"});

GrammarBuilder connector3 = new Choices(new string[] { "over", "on", "under", "in" });

GrammarBuilder graBui5 = new GrammarBuilder();
graBui3.Append(questionType, 1, 1); //min repeat = 1 and max repeat = 1
graBui3.Append(connector, 1, 1);
graBui3.Append(connector2, 1, 1);
graBui3.Append(connector3, 1, 2); //Tried adding 2 for maxRepeat but didn't work

Grammar Gra5 = new Grammar(graBui5);
```

For example, referring to the above code: How do I recognize this?

> > The Cat jumped over on

I need to recognize 2 words from the 'connector3' GrammarBuilder. How do I get this done? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Speech Recognizing Multiple Words together? (Recognize a sentence)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26180040/c-sharp-speech-recognizing-multiple-words-together-recognize-a-sentence)

Comment: You already asked this question before.

Comment: errrr that is completely different o.O Did you even read the question

Comment: Sure I did, you still don't understand the basics. If you want to recognize sequence you do not need the choices at all, you need just sequence "over on", "over in", "under on", "under in"

Comment: And instead of GrammarBuilder connector2 = new Choices(new string[] { "jumped"}); you just create new GrammarBuilder("jumped"); without choice of 1 element.

Answer (score -1):

Use a hashset collection before appending the text.

So in your method **Append()**, store the appended text into a hashset to prevent multiple text. But take note that doing it would prevent the same words like **The**, so in that scenario this approach would fail.

Read about HashSet here: [HashSet](http://www.dotnetperls.com/hashset)

EDIT:

If you want to look what words were repeated, I'd use Distinct and Except to get the words repeated in a collection.

Lets say you're storing the appended text, use distinct make all records unique, and then Except it with the original to get the words removed from distinct and the remaining should be the repeated.

Read more here: [Distinct](http://www.dotnetperls.com/distinct), [Except](http://www.dotnetperls.com/except)

Comment: Actually that's the opposite of what I want bro :) I WANT to recognize multiple words from the choices :)